# Does C++11 provide hashing functions for std::type_info?

Tags: c++, c++11, rtti, unordered-map, typeinfo

I'm still working on a good solution to my [One-Of-A-Type Container Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221501/oneofatype-container-storing-one-each-of-a-given-type-in-a-container-am-i-o) -- and upon reflection I think it would be nice to be able to just use something like a `std::map<std::type_info, boost::any>`. Unfortunately, `std::type_info` does not define an `operator<`, and I think it'd be unreasonable for it to define one.

However, it does seem reasonable to define a hash function for it, because you could simply use the singleton address of the `std::type_info` object as a reasonable "hash". Therefore, you'd be able to put a `std::type_info` into a `std::unordered_map` as the key.

Does C++11 provide such a hash function? Would using the memory address of the `std::type_info` singleton be a bad hash strategy?

Comment: It's not a singleton, by the way, but a statically allocated object.

Comment: @GMan: What's the difference?

Comment: If it was a singleton, there would be exactly one `type_info` object.  Since there are multiple types in a program, there must be more than one `type_info` object in the program.

Comment: @James: Ah-- I meant one singleton per type. My point was that I thought there would be at most one type_info per type.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fact that `type_info` is not less-than comparable isn't as much a problem for using it as a map key as the fact that `type_info` is non-copyable.  :-)

In C++03, `type_info` has a `before()` member function that provides an ordering of `type_info` objects.

In C++11, `type_info` has a `hash_code()` member function (C++11 §18.7.1/7):

> ```
> size_t hash_code() const throw();
> ```
>
> *Returns:* an unspeciﬁed value, except that within a single execution of the program, it shall return the same value for any two `type_info` objects which compare equal.
>
> *Remark:* an implementation should return different values for two `type_info` objects which do not compare equal.

`type_info` objects resulting from the `typeid` operator exist until the end of the program, so it is safe to use a `type_info*` as a map key.  However, to the best of my knowledge, there is no guarantee that if you apply `typeid` to two objects of the same type you will get two references to the same `type_info` object.

If you do use `type_info*` as a map key, I'd use a custom comparator that dereferences the pointers and compares the `type_info` objects themselves (using the aforementioned `before()` or `hash_code()` for ordering).

Comment: @James: D'oh! Perhaps I can use `std::type_info *` (because there's only once instance of a particular type_info class?) ?

Comment: @James: That could be difficult because `std::type_info` objects don't provide an efficient way to compare themselves. Looks like it's back to the home brew solution for me :/

Comment: @Billy: Wait, what? They have `operator==`, and although two objects of the same type may not return the same instance of a `type_info` object, they must compare equal (and generated the same hash).

Comment: @GMan: Yes, but std::map requires `operator<`, not `operator==`. I suppose I can use `std::unordered_map` but I'm trying to leave as much in C++03 as reasonably possible. (That said, if there was an off the shelf way to solve this in C++0x I'd consider that, hence the question :) )

Comment: @Billy:  You can, however, write a `bool compare(const type_info* x, const type_info* y) { return x->before(*y); }`, or compare the hash codes returned by `hash_code()` using `operator<`.

Comment: However, upon re-reading the text from the C++0x FCD, I don't think I'd rely on `hash_code()` returning a unique value for two different `type_info` objects... that "should" word makes me very, very nervous.  I'd stick with `before()`.

Comment: @James: Ah, that 'should' is dubious. Makes sense though; in the same way `name()` can `return 0;`, so can `hash_code()`. I think `before()` is the best option here.

Comment: @James + @GMan: Then the real question is why the standard does not define `std::type_info::operator<` ...

Comment: @Billy: Likely because, semantically, it shouldn't.  What does it mean to say one type is less than another?

Comment: @Billy:  I'd guess it's because while the ordering is guaranteed to be consistent within a single execution of a program, the ordering is not guaranteed to be consistent across separate executions.  I don't think it's typical for objects to compare differently in different executions of a given program.  However, that's kind of lame and I just made that up.  I could be completely wrong.  :-)

Comment: @Dennis: I don't know but apparently they have already thought of one, because there is a `before` member. In this case I don't even care about whether the objects are really less than -- I just need equivalence tests to work.

Comment: The hash function isn't *required* to return unique values because it's a hash function.  A hashing container must deal with hash collisions.  Ideally, the compiler would generate a perfect hash function for the typeinfo objects as they're all known at compile time.  The standard isn't requiring it, possibly because it could be non-trivial.

Comment: @caspin: the compiler could do so (perfect hash) for a single library, but how would you coordinate multiple libraries, knowing that template types are shared among them while other types will only appear in one ? It gets tricky...

Comment: @Matthieu:  Well, the `type_info` objects for different types must be distinct (they cannot compare equal to each other), so they must occupy different locations in memory and if you are on a platform where `sizeof (size_t) == sizeof (uintptr_t)`, then you can simply cast the address of the `type_info` struct and use that as its hash code.  This works for most (but certainly not all) systems.

Comment: @James McNellis: I am not that confident, would a `basic_string<char, allocator<char> >` have one instance per library, and thus possibly one `typeinfo` per library... and thus a variety of possible addresses (one per library) ? I really think templates could mess things up here...

Comment: @Matthieu:  Oops; you're right.  I was neglecting what I said earlier, that applying `typeid` to two instances of a type might yield different `type_info` instances that compare equal.

Comment: Please see the answer below. I have no idea why this answer is the accepted one, but type_index is clearly the way to go (since the question is about C++11, for C++03 this answer can be useful)

Comment: @EFraim Well, `type_index` was added in C++11, and this answer was both written and accepted a full year before C++11 was finished.

Comment: Waring: this answer is partially incorrect! According to https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_info/hash_code: "No other guarantees are given: type_info objects referring to different types may have the same hash_code (although the standard recommends that implementations avoid this as much as possible), and hash_code for the same type can change between invocations of the same program."

Answer (score 13):

You could also use [type_index](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/type_index), it safely holds a pointer to a type_info, it's copyable, comparable and a hash function is provided for standard containers.