# how to create a container that takes one object of each kind?

Tags: c++, stl, generic-programming, typeid, typeinfo

I tried to create a container for posible metadata that can be attached to my objects. I can guarantee that there will be at most one object af each kind attached to my class but there is no limit for object of different type to attach. for example I can't attach two instances of `wordInfo` to an object but instances of `wordInfo` and `phraseInfo` classes can be attached to an object at a same time. here is what I did so far to get it done.

```
class object
{
    std::map <std::type_info, object*> mMetaData;
    public:
    inline void attachMetaData(object* pData)
    {
        mMetaData[typeid(*pData)] = pData;
    }
    template <class T> inline std::enableif<std::is_base_of<object,T>::value, T*>::type getMetaData()
    {
        if (mMetaData.find(typeid(T)) == mMetaData.end())
            return NULL;
        else
            return mMetaData[typeid(T)];
    }
    template <class T> inline std::enableif<std::is_base_of<object,T>::value, void>::type detachMetaData()
    {
        mMetaData.erase(typeid(T));
    }
}
```

the code above had a compile error : less operator was not defined for `std::type_info` so I defined some less class specifically for `std::type_info` and pass it as the third template parameter of map class like this:

```
struct typeinfoless
{
    bool operator()(std::type_info& left, std::type_info& right)
    {
        return left.hash() < right.hash();
    }
}
std::map <std::type_info, object*, typeinfoless> mMetaData;
```

but then I encountered another error which I don't know how to resolve, `std::type_info` has private constructor and even private copy constructor, so I can't even derive some class from it. any idea how can I fix this problem? or any other possible way to create my `object` class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OneOfAType container -- storing one each of a given type in a container -- am I off base here?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221501/oneofatype-container-storing-one-each-of-a-given-type-in-a-container-am-i-o)

Comment: also, the discussion in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552135/will-c0x-provide-hashing-functions-for-stdtype-info is probably even more approriate

Comment: @cubbi: seems not, i've got the hash function which was the main question in the one you marked. I'm not sure if it's VC++ implementation or what but type_info has the hash function and I can easily use it, my problem is with the creating a map class with type_info as key because i got a error type_info::type_info is inaccessible.

Comment: @cubbi: and about your first suggestion, it seems I can use that to solve my problem but it doesn't give an advice how to use standard std::type_info or typeid object in c++, it redefines RTTI objects themselves.

Comment: @cubbi: typeid has one big feature over the answers in your first discussion: you can both call `typeid(int)` and `int i; typeid(i)` and they both return same thing. which I don't know how to generate using the answer there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a wrapper class for std::type_info, similar to the following:

```
class TypeWrapper
{
    private const std::type_info &mInfo;
    public TypeWrapper(const std::type_info &info) : mInfo(info)
    {
    }
    // Functions required by a key into a std::map.
};
```

Use `TypeWrapper` as your key into your map.

Comment: seems the return value of typeid is not `std::type_info` and not `std::type_info&`. so I can't call `TypeWrapper(typeid(int))`

Answer (score 7):

Apologies for answering an ancient question but this was the first result on google when I tried to figure it out. Instead of creating a wrapper class you should use the `std::type_index` wrapper class as the key into your map.